# How to properly setup Windows7 to use Selenium with Firefox [TDD with Python]?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm getting my system (Windows 7 Pro 64 bit, Python 3.5 through Anaconda) setup to use Firefox through selenium to follow the book *Test Driven Development with Python.* Python keeps throwing error `WebDriverException: 'geckodriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH.` even though I've set my system path to point to geckodriver's folder (and restarted 3 times).

If I point python/selenium to `geckodriver.exe`'s exact location I get the following error

```
OSError: [WinError 216] This version of %1 is not compatible with the
version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information
to see whether you need a x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program,
and then contact the software publisher
```

At this point I'm not sure if the error version `%1` has to do with firefox being the wrong version (I've tried 64 and 32 bit), the geckodriver, selenium, or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Selenium used to reference a driver called `wires.exe` ([github-geckodriver issue 90](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/90#issuecomment-226154811)). As of `Selenium3` that driver has been replaced with `geckodriver.exe`. Install/upgrade to the latest selenium by running `pip install "selenium>=3.0.0"`
2. [Download the latest geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.11.1) for your platform: as of this writing that would be `geckodriver-v0.11.1-win64.zip` for 64 bit or `geckodriver-v0.11.1-win32.zip` for 32 bit. In your case the `version %1` error has to do with an incorrect geckodriver version. Extract this zip to `C:\Users\YourUserName\Downloads\selenium_driver`
3. Install the [Firefox Extended Support Release](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/all/?q=English%20(US)) setting the custom installation path to `C:\Program Files\Mozilla FirefoxESR` if on 64 bit or `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla FirefoxESR` if on 32 bit.

If [setting the Windows PATH](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) to `C:\Users\YourUserName\Downloads\selenium_driver` doesn't seem to work (so that `selenium` can find `geckdriver.exe`) you can instead specify its directory in your Python script as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
gecko = r'C:\Users\YourUserName\Downloads\selenium_driver\geckodriver.exe'
ffox_binary = FirefoxBinary(r'C:\Program Files\Mozilla FirefoxESR\firefox.exe') #for 64 bit installation
#ffox_binary = FirefoxBinary(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla FirefoxESR\firefox.exe') #for 32 bit installation
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=ffox_binary, executable_path=gecko)  
browser.get('http://localhost:8000')
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have downloaded [GeckoDriver for win-64 bit](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.11.1) as you have 64-bit machine. Now copy paste downloaded GeckoDriver executable inside 'Script' folder(this folder is present inside the root folder where python is installed in your system). Now set the path of python root folder and 'Script' folder in Environment variable

```
C:\..Python; //path of python root folder 
C:\..Python\Scripts; //path of python 'Script' folder
```

[image]

Don't forget to restart your system for the changes to take effect & try this sample code

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://google.com")
```