# I cannot open RIDE Ide due to "ImportError: cannot import name rebot"

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, robotframework

When i try to open Ride from cmd prompt, i get below error

The Full Stack Trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\ride.py", line 20, in <module>
    from robotide import main
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
    from robot.errors import DataError
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\lib\robot\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from robot.rebot import rebot, rebot_cli
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\lib\robot\rebot.py", line 273, in <module>
    from robot.run import RobotFramework
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\lib\robot\run.py", line 339, in <module>
    from robot.output import LOGGER, Output, pyloggingconf
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\lib\robot\output\pyloggingconf.py", line 17, in <module>
    from robot.api import logger
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\lib\robot\api\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from robot.running import TestSuite
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\lib\robot\running\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from .model import TestSuite
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\lib\robot\running\model.py", line 24, in <module>
    from .namespace import Namespace
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\lib\robot\running\namespace.py", line 26, in <module>
    from .userkeyword import UserLibrary
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\lib\robot\running\userkeyword.py", line 27, in <module>
    from .arguments import UserKeywordArguments
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\lib\robot\running\arguments\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .argumentmapper import ArgumentMapper
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\lib\robot\running\arguments\argumentmapper.py", line 15, in <module>
    from robotide.lib.robot.errors import DataError
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\lib\robot\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from robot.rebot import rebot, rebot_cli
ImportError: cannot import name rebot
```

`Ride.py` is located in `C:\Python27\Scripts\`. Also, `rebot.bat` is located in `C:\Python27\Scripts\rebot.bat`

Can someone please help.

Comment: Have u installed robotframework?

Comment: Yes. I've install robotframework 3.0, Python 2.7 and selenium2library.

Comment: How did you install RIDE?
What was the path when you started ride,py? From c:\\ ?

Answer (score 0):

Initially I was having similar problem in starting RIDE in command prompt. I uninstall python and followed the below steps for my 64 bit machine, now its working well for me. You can also give it a try

1. [Install python 2.7.12(Windows x86 MSI installer)](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2712/)
2. [Set environment path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40834238/how-to-properly-setup-windows7-to-use-selenium-with-firefox-tdd-with-python/40837887#40837887)
3. pip install selenium
4. pip install robotframework
5. pip install robotframework-selenium2library
6. pip install robotframework-ride
7. [Install wxPython installer for python 27 & win 64 machine](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython/files/wxPython/2.8.12.1/) (wxPython2.8-win64-unicode-2.8.12.1-py27)
8. Start RIDE from command prompt  ride.py